# Escape characters on ffmpeg.exe batch file in Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file

I have a complicated ffmpeg.exe command in a batch file... I'm not sure how to escape the special characters correctly:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920" -vframes 1 -pixel_format yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -hide_banner -loglevel panic -q:v 1 -y -vf "drawtext=expansion=strftime:fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf':text='%a %Y-%m-%d %I\:%M\:%S%p':box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5" c920.jpg
```

It works great when run from command prompt, as soon as I run it inside a batch file, the text overlay displays 'Y-d M:p' instead of 'Mon 2017-10-23 04:45:18PM'

If I remove the text overlay part (below) it works fine.

```
-vf "drawtext=expansion=strftime:fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf':text='%a %Y-%m-%d %I\:%M\:%S%p':box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5"
```

Comment: Try doubling up the `%`s replacing each single `%` with `%%`. See [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes "The % character has a special meaning for command line parameters and FOR parameters.
To treat a percent as a regular character, double it:"

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. -vf "drawtext=expansion=strftime:fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf':text='%%a %%Y-%%m-%%d %%I\:%%M\:%%S%%p':box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'm not sure how to escape the special characters correctly

You need to double up the `%`s and replace each single `%` with `%%`:

> The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters and `FOR` parameters.
>   To treat a percent as a regular character, double it.

Source [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters 
and Quotes

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters 
  and Quotes